# Symfony2 insert in chaining related columns

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hello there StackOverflowers !
My Question for today is to how insert data to dabase in chaing with related columns.
So here is my code.

> ```
>        $firstEntity->setUserName("login")
>                     ->setUserPassword("password")
>                     ->setUserEmail("email")
>          $this->em->persist($firstEntity);
>          $this->em->flush();
>          $secondEntity = new secondEntity();
>          $secondEntity->setSurname("surname")
>                       ->setName("name")
>                       ->setCity("city");
>          $this->em->persist($secondEntity);
>          $this->em->flush();
> ```
>
> And now i have related columns one to one: "first_entity_id" with "second_entity_id". And here is my Question how to do this in one chaining ? Like :
>
> > ```
> >        $firstEntity->setUserName("login")
> >                     ->setUserPassword("password")
> >                     ->setUserEmail("email")
> >                     ->setSecondDetailsId()
> >                     ->setSurname("surname") //from second entity
> >                     ->setName("name") //from second entity
> >                     ->setCity("city"); //from second entity
> >          $this->em->persist($secondEntity);
> >          $this->em->flush();
> > ```
> >
> > Greetings

Comment: Yup. What was the message you are getting on trying your code ?

Comment: Using of undefined method setSurname in class firstEntity